# Make me a shape

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, random

The game [shapez.io](https://shapez.io) has a huge variety of shapes you can produce, such as:

[image]

Each shape has a unique *short code*, for example the above is `CrWbScRu`.

This means, going clockwise from top right, red circle (`Cr`), blue wedge (`Wb`), cyan star (`Sc`), uncolored rectangle (`Ru`).

There are four different shapes:

- Rectangle - `R`
- Wedge - `W`
- Star - `S`
- Circle - `C`

And eight different colours:

- uncolored - `u`
- red - `r`
- green - `g`
- blue - `b`
- yellow - `y`
- purple - `p`
- cyan - `c`
- white - `w`

A quadrant is made out of one of each of these - (shape)(color). A quadrant can also be *empty* with `--`. This means there are 33 possible quadrants.

Four quadrants concatenated together make a *layer*, of which there are \$33^4 - 1 = 1185920\$ possibilities. You can't have an empty layer (`--------`). These layers can be stacked on top of one another by joining with `:` - the code `CyCyCyCy:SrSrSrSr` looks like:

[image]

Shapes can be stacked up to 4. This means there are \$\left(33^{4}-1\right)+\left(33^{4}-1\right)^{2}+\left(33^{4}-1\right)^{3}+\left(33^{4}-1\right)^{4} = \$ 1.97 septillion possible shapes total.

Your challenge is to randomly generate one of these.

Your generation does not have to be uniformly random, as long as every possible shape has a nonzero chance of being chosen.

### Specs

- Each *quadrant* is one of `SWCR` followed by one of `ugbrycpw`, or `--`.
- A *layer* is four *quadrants* concatenated together.
- A *shape* is 1-4 *layers* joined by `:`
- You should generate a not-necessarily-uniformly-random *shape*.

You can view shapes at https://viewer.shapez.io/.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Comment: This should definitely be made into a `graphical-output` challenge.

Comment: Would forcing the first quadrant to be non-empty (with the remaining 3 being randomly empty or not) fall within the scope of not being uniformly random?

Comment: @xigoi That's my next idea... that would be taking a shortcode and printing it though.

Comment: @Shaggy No, because then you can't generate shapes with empty first quadrants.

Comment: @emanresuA Right, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>35</s> <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

+5 to prevent empty output which would've occured with probability \$33^{-16}\$
-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen!

Quite slow, generates \$33^4\$ possible layers 4 times and chooses a random one each time. Layers of all `-` are removed.

```
[₄ε‘¥„W‘’»Õpcw’â„--ª4ãΩJ}'-8×K':ýDĀ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@lFTy7mtjxpmHFr6qGFeOJDxqGHmod2HpxYklwNZhxcBRXV1D60yObz43EqvWnVdi8PTvdWtDu91OdKg/P//f13dvHzdnMSqSgA)

At the cost of two bytes this can actually run fast: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2tDM59zWRw0zDi191DAvHMh41DDz0O7DUwuSy4Gsw4uAorq6h1adW1lrcniLl7quxeHp3upWh/e6HGlQ/v8fAA)

Because every quadrant in each layer has a \$1\$ in \$33\$ chance of being empty the resulting shapes are quite noisy:

[image: SpSgCgRy:CyRgRcSw:RrCuScRu:ScSyWuCp]

---

```python
[    ...    Dg#              # until the the output is not empty, do the following:

₄                            # push constant 1000
  ε                     }    # for each digit in this number:
   ‘¥„W‘                     #   dictionary compressed string "SRCW"
        ’»Õpcw’              #   dictionary compressed string "rugbypcw"
               â             #   cartesian product of the two strings
                „--ª         #   append "--" to this list
                    4ã       #   4th cartesian power, all 4-element combinations from the length-2 strings
                      Ω      #   choose a random one
                       J     #   join into a single string

'-8×                         # string of 8 -'s
    K                        # remove all occurences from the list
     ':ý                     # join the list by ":"
```

Comment: Damnit! Beaten by better string compression! :(

Comment: `4L` to `₄` for -1. Also, the challenge states it can't have an empty layer, not that the entire output can't be empty. So `'-8×K':ýDgĀ#` is incorrect, since it only checks if the entire shape is empty. You can fix this with `':ýD'-8×å≠#`, which is also 1 byte shorter.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for the -1! But for the second part of your comment the challenge states *A shape is 1-4 layers [...]*, and since layers can't be empty this implies the output is not empty. `'-8×K` removes empty layers, no? With your suggestion the output always has 4 layers.

Comment: Ah, I misread the challenge regarding the second part. You're indeed correct that it has 1-4 layers, and empty layers should be removed, so your approach was correct. I think you can remove the `g` for another -1, though? `Ā` will be truthy for a non-empty string and falsey for `""`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes that works, thanks again

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>38</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
“SWCR”p“¬,ĖṆḷ⁸»Żṗ4XʋⱮ4ẸƇƊṆ¿o⁾--j”:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zgcOegRw1zC4DMQ2t0jkx7uLPt4Y7tjxp3HNp9dPfDndNNIk51P9q4zuThrh3H2o91AaUP7c9/1LhPVzcLqM3q/38A)

This *just* about finishes on TIO most of the time (it has a \$1\$ in \$33^{16}\$ chance of taking longer), taking around 55 seconds. Full program, as we require Jelly's smash-printing to get the correct output

-4 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!

The first sample output I got was:

[image: generated shape]

[External link](https://viewer.shapez.io?SbSyRwWy.WwWgRyCg.RrScRuWc.WgCyRuCr)

## How it works

```
“SWCR”p“¬,ĖṆḷ⁸»Żṗ4XʋⱮ4ẸƇƊṆ¿o⁾--j”: - Main link. No arguments. Left argument = 0
                        Ɗ          - Group the previous 3 links into a monad f(_): (ignores the argument)
“SWCR”                             -   Set the return value to “SWCR”
                   ʋ               -   Group the previous 4 links into a dyad g(“SWCR”, i): (ignores i)
       “¬,ĖṆḷ⁸»                    -     Compressed string: “rugbypcw”
      p                            -     Cartesian product with “SWCR”
               Ż                   -     Prepend a zero (represents “--”)
                ṗ4                 -     4th Cartesian power
                  X                -     Choose a random list
                    Ɱ4             -   Yield [g(“SWCR”,1), g(“SWCR”,2), g(“SWCR”,3), g(“SWCR”,4)]
                      ẸƇ           -   Remove any that are just zeros
                          ¿        - While:
                         Ṇ         -   The left argument is falsey ([] or 0)
                        Ɗ          -   Set the left argument to f(_)
                           o⁾--    - Replace all zeros with “--”
                               j”: - Join by ”: and smash-print
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan Corrected

Comment: Good job golfing :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I still think I can beat 05AB1E somehow :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I couldn't beat 35 with any patches of a single link, so I've gone with your 35 byte one. Thanks for the golfs!

Comment: Aha, I saw the `4µ` and the length of `“SWCR”`, and thought to myself, "it must be possible to make a save using that somehow!" [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zgcOegRw1zC4DMQ2t0jkx7uLPt4Y7tjxp3HNp9dPfDndNNIk51P9q4LuHhrh3H2o91AaUP7c9/1LhPVzcLqM3q/38A) :D ...EDIT: although now the `4` can go back in if we want [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zgcOegRw1zC4DMQ2t0jkx7uLPt4Y7tjxp3HNp9dPfDndNNIk51P9q4zuThrh3H2o91AaUP7c9/1LhPVzcLqM3q/38A)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh nice! I was trying to do something with that and `)`, but I couldn't figure out a way to get the entire string as an argument

Comment: It's hilarious how there are 2 other people who also thought: "let's do 4th cartesian power, who cares about runtime". I thought I was being way too goofy

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 129 bytes

```python
from random import*
print(':'.join(''.join(sample(q,4))for q in[[i+j for i in'RWSC'for j in'urgbypcw']*4+['--']*3]*randint(1,4)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaKhbqetl5WfmaahD6eLE3IKcVI1CHRNNzbT8IoVChcy86OhM7SwFEC8TyFMPCg92VgfxskC80qL0pMqC5HL1WC0T7Wh1XV0gwzhWC2QbyAJDkEGa//8DAA)

For each layer, 4 items are picked from a distribution containing 3 empty quadrants and the other shape-colour combinations 4 times.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 38 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

This version has a *very* high probability of having all 4 layers, using a similar approach as [Level's Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233743/58974) of generating all 4 layers, removing the ones consisting entirely of empty quadrants and making a recursive call if there are none left.

```
4Æ"RWCS"ï`Õ½wbgp` p-² ö4 qÃfÈr-Ãq': ªß
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=NMYiUldDUyLvYNW9d2JncGAgcC2yIPY0IHHDZshyLcNxJzogqt8)

### Original, 39 bytes

```
Ò4ö)ÆÈr-}a@"RWCS"ï`Õ½wbgp` p-² ö4 q
q':
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0jT2KcbIci19YUAiUldDUyLvYNW9d2JncGAgcC2yIPY0IHEKcSc6)

```
Ò4ö)ÆÈr-}a@"RWCS"ï`Õ½wbgp` p-² ö4 q\nq':
Ò                                            :Negate the bitwise not of (i.e., increment)
 4ö                                          :  Random int in the range [0,4)
   )                                         :End bitwise op
    Æ                                        :Map the range [0,Ò4ö)
     È                                       :  Left function taking a string as argument
      r-                                     :    Remove all "-"s
        }                                    :  End function
         a                                   :  Return the first result of the right function that returns truthy (non-empty string) when passed through the left
          @                                  :  Right function
           "RWCS"ï                           :    Cartesian product of "RWCS" and
                  `Õ½wbgp`                   :      Compressed string "ucrywbgp"
                           p                 :    Push
                            -²               :      "-" duplicated
                               ö4            :    Choose 4 random elements
                                  q          :    Join
                                     q':     :Join with ":"
```

Comment: How does this prevent generating empty layers?

Comment: @ovs, the right function generates the layer, which could possibly be entirely empty, and it is then run through the left function which removes all `-`s in it. If that produces an empty string then the process is repeated until a valid layer is generated.

Answer (score 4):

## C#<sub>[9.0]</sub> - <s>191, 235, 228, 204,</s> 203 Bytes (Condensed)

```
static Random r=new();static string g(){var z="";for(int j,i,l=r.Next(1,4);l-->0;z+=":")for(i=j=0;i++<4;)z+=r.Next()%8<1&&j++<3?"--":$"{"CRWS"[r.Next(0,3)]}{"rgbypcuw"[r.Next(0,7)]}";return z.Trim(':');}
```

- `+44` bytes due to a missed requirement.
- `-5` bytes by reducing `GetShape` to `g` per [@emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)'s recommendation.
- `-24` bytes by using `var`, consolidating declarations and using constant strings per [@Johan du Toit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/johan-du-toit).
- `-1` byte by swapping `==0` for `<1` per [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

##### How it Works

```
// Create a new random number generator using C# 9.0's `new` invocation.
static Random r = new();
static string g() {

    // Create a variable to store the possible shapes.
    string s = "CRWS",

            // Create a variable to store the possible colors.
            c = "rgbypcuw",

            // Create a variable to store the result.
            z = "";

    // Create an iteration variable to iteratively create between 1 and 4 layers randomly.
    // Evaluate for stop then decrement.
    // Append `:` to the result.
    for (int l = r.Next(1, 4); l-- > 0; z+=":")

        // Create an iteration variable to iteratively create the four quadrants.
        // Create a variable for tracking the number of empty quadrants.
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i++ < 4;)

            // If we haven't reached the maximum number of allowed empty quadrants, a new one can still be added.
            // Use a random number to determine if we should create an empty quadrant.
            // Since && short circuits, the increment of J doesn't occur unless we're adding an empty quadrant.
            if (r.Next() % 8 == 0 && j++ < 3)

                // Add an empty quadrant.
                z += "--";

            // Otherwise, add a shape and color from the variables above,
            //      using a random index within the bounds of the variables lengths.
            else
                z += $"{s[r.Next(0, 3)]}{c[r.Next(0, 7)]}";

    // Return the result and remove any trailing `:`.
    return z.Trim(':');
}
```

##### Sample Output

I called the method in a `for` loop over 10 iterations to sample the output for this post:

```
--CyCpCb:RpCu--Rc
RpCyWbWc:RcWuWyWc
CyWy--Cr:RrWpWuWg
Wp--WuRc
RpCcCgWp
CbWuWgCu:--RcRbWg:CcCuCpCc
RgRpCyCu:CbWyWuCu
CgCuRpCu
CyRc--Ru:WuRuRbRu:--CgRbWr
WpCgCpRu
```

##### Resulting Image Sample

I ran the shape code `CbWuWgCu:--RcRbWg:CcCuCpCc` through and got this result:
[image: Screenshot of the image produced by the aforementioned code.]

Comment: Btw, you can probably replace getShape with `g` or something.

Comment: I like the `Random r=new();` bit, haven't seen that before!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 51 bytes

```
⪫ＥＥ⊕‽⁴⊕‽⊖Ｘ³³¦⁴⭆Ｅ⁴÷ιＸ³³λ⎇﹪λ³³⁺§RWSCλ§urgbypcw÷λ⁴--¦:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY49C4MwEIb/Ssh0Qpzi1E6lLhYE0ULnNAk2EBNJo9Zfn0altUOH446H9@P4gzlumQ6hcsp4uFhloGT9OoXhTnbSeCmgZkbYDrIkIegPz@WOKjtJB5QSFNXJYmh8DG8/sdmS4HM1KiFBEbTr9aq@SmeYm6G0YtAWNEGURlzp4QknXxghX4DrW3PGi4OgLxtce597PuHfAr29QRBOU7wdh7iPIYR01G8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    ‽⁴                                              Random integer 0-3
   ⊕                                                Incremented
  Ｅ                                                 Map over implicit range
         Ｘ³³¦⁴                                      33⁴
        ⊖                                           Decremented
       ‽                                            Random integer
      ⊕                                             Incremented
 Ｅ                                                  Map over random integers
               Ｅ⁴                                   Map over quadrants
                 ÷ι                                 Current random integer
                 ÷                                  Integer divide by
                    ³³                              Literal integer `33`
                   Ｘ                                Raised to power
                      λ                             Current quadrant
              ⭆                                     Map over values and join
                         λ                          Current value
                        ﹪ ³³                        Modulo literal `33`
                       ⎇                            If nonzero then
                             §RWSCλ                 Cyclically indexed colour
                            ⁺                       Concatenated with
                                   §urgbypcw        Shape cyclically indexed by
                                             λ      Current value
                                            ÷       Integer divide by
                                              ⁴     Literal integer `4`
                                               --   Else literal string `--`
⪫                                                 : Join with literal `:`
                                                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>95</s> 138 bytes

```perl
{@q=(qw(: --),map{$s=$_;map$s.$_,ugbrycpw=~/./g}C,R,W,S);@i=map$_%5?$==1+rand
33:0,1..rand 19;@i%5==4&&" @i "!~/ (1 ){4}/||redo;say@q[@i]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrdCoIwGIDh865iyRSluTV0Bzk@GnQHddBBhFiKCP3ohon4c@tLz94XnrrQL2FbU6CfoHwv7aAa8JvOT1AYBuSd1QM2gFO5FDYUp6QtH7p/1h3MjLJyOpEzuZJLIFUFq0ldccQAfKezT76JomRPOKXrIH5YkCsAYs9zkKqQs50Z8jkKhnhi46iL/CtN1qvmpqr7ZO0f)

Comment: How does this avoid the possibility of empty layers?

Comment: @Shaggy I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 137 bytes

```c
#define r rand()
m;b;q(){m=r;m&30||q();}f(){for(q(b=5+r%4*5);--b;)printf(b%5?m&1<<b%5?"%c%c":"--":":"+!q(),"WRSC"[r%4],"rugbywcp"[r%8]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU5NC4IwAL37K9ZC2dKBUUI4pUP/oA4dwoObTgZt6TQk1L/eml0e7z14H5w0nFu7rWohdQ0MMKWuEPYUZbRDeFK5oSo4xPPsFF2Es8TLoA6xPAmNf9wlmBLCKG6N1INAzE/OKthn2Uqgz30OU0iIgxSGG9cRwfv1doEPly0iaN4N@4y8XfWpcANWlVIjDCYPgP7/ZZCqRjHG1DlunnqL/XLxLJvekvEH)

-5 bytes thanks ceilingcat!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `rR`, 37 bytes

```
\:4℅ƛ«3⟩∑ḣ`«`SWRC`Ẋ‛--J33²²‹℅τ∑₅8ε-;j
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rR&code=%5C%3A4%E2%84%85%C6%9B%C2%AB3%E2%9F%A9%E2%88%91%E1%B8%A3%60%C2%AB%60SWRC%60%E1%BA%8A%E2%80%9B--J33%C2%B2%C2%B2%E2%80%B9%E2%84%85%CF%84%E2%88%91%E2%82%858%CE%B5-%3Bj&inputs=&header=&footer=)

This uses a quite neat custom-base-decompression-based approach to ensure there'll never be an empty layer. It basically generates a random number between 1 and \$33^4 - 1\$, decompresses it with the key as all possible quadrants (with `--` first, so 0 can never occur, so empty layers won't either).

```
  4℅ƛ                              ;  # array of length (random 1-4) filled with...
                       33²²‹℅         # Random integer between 1 and 33^4-1 inclusive 
                             τ        # Decompressed by...
                  Ẋ                   # Cartesian product of...
     «3⟩∑ḣ`«                          # Compressed string `bcgpruwy`
            `SWRC`                    # String literal `SWRC`
                   ‛--J               # Prepend a `--`
                              ∑       # Concatenate all this
                               ₅8ε-   # Pad with `-` from the start
                                    j # Join the whole thing by...
\:                                    # Semicolons.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>117</s> 114 bytes

```ruby
->{s=((0..19).map{|i|i%5<1??::"-SWCR"[(r=rand 40)/8]+"rgbpucyw-"[r<8?8:r%8]}*'').gsub ?:+?-*8,''
s>''?s[1,99]:f[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjBCoMgAADQ@74ihFArXcEGKpWH/cF22EE8ZFvhoRGajLC@vcHe8blg1mNoDtJG3yBUUlpxTKdujpvdbHqtKymFAOTxvN2BQq5x3eeVXEp8ZjoHbjRz6NcvAcrVTDLhUqb3DEJMRx9MIkUuScYKCE@@hVB6VRWcazEovR@c08VObx/nsPjkXz8)

A function returning a string.

**Commented code (original version)**

```ruby
->{s=
 ((0..19).map{|i|i%5<1?     #Iterate 20 times to make an array. if i%5==0  
 ?::                        #put a colon, else...
  "-SWCR"[(r=rand 40)/8]+   #Select a shape
  (r<8??-:"rgbpucyw"[r%8])  #If selected shape is - then put another -, else put a colour
  }*'').                    #Convert the 20-element array into a string
  gsub(?:+?-*8,'')          #Delete all instances of :--------
  s<?!?f[]:s[1,99]}         #If s is empty, recursively call f[] to try again. Else output s (minus the initial colon)
```

Comment: Won't this always generate 4 layers instead of a random number?

Comment: @Shaggy it can generate empty layers (with a one in 5**4=625 probability, which is quite high) which are then deleted. What remains is anything between 0 and 4 layers. In the case of 0 layers (very rare) it calls itself again recursively to avoid ouputting nothing.

Comment: Ah. I'd read it as the replace & repeat being done for each layer, rather than the final image. Interesting approach; I wonder if I can save anything on my Japt solution by doing something similar?

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <sup><del>263</del></sup> 253 bytes

-10 thanks to ceilingcat! Forgot that `|` exists and that ternary `if`s can be written without parentheses. D'oh!

```java
String f(int i){var r=new Random();var q=""+"SWCR-".charAt(r.nextInt(5));q+=q.equals("-")?'-':"ugbrycpw".charAt(r.nextInt(8));return i<1?(f(2)+f(2)+f(2)+f(3)).substring(1):i<9?i>2|r.nextInt(2)<1?(":"+f(9)+f(9)+f(9)+f(9)).replace(":--------",f(1)):"":q;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA9T8MwEIb3/IqTl/oUYqVFSDRuqBATAwztwIAY3MQpLomTOE5LVfrbg9NEAiE8vNJ9vHfnZyf2ItilH50qqtJY2LmYtVblbCV0Whbc85JcNA08CaVPHoDSVppMJBKe@xBgbY3SW0ioq4BG7pJnz0ljhVUJdGM9u9QVnvbCgIm1PMCwgSLvU3VMiE/WLw@rgLDkXZh7Sw3T8tM@aktvEHntxzWTdSvyhpKA4HISTCLSbjfmmFSHf0y3zmSkbY0GtZguaUZn6P@Wa0TWtJvmciGdYqQW86W6m339zJhh7yQRce1z/CPIjKxyx8I1BOMjV5mbhBEhUc3PHe9RVO0mdyhGIvtSpVA4nHRA8/oGAgeWkJUGBlAQQ8j7u8OQK99HGBp64MfGyoKVrWWV89tcu5@FOJI/d98)

Took forever to find something promising, ow my head...
This won't win any prices, but I liked the approach so here it is anyways. It uses the same function recursively with a different parameter to build different parts of the string.
I hope I find the template for Java lambdas again, I keep forgetting how the boilerplate needs to look for them to work :(

### EDIT:

Function lamdas aren't shorter in this case, since you don't call but `apply()` them, which is WAY longer. Still, thanks for the template `Johan du Troit`!

#### Explained:

```java
// function is called with 0 to start
String f(int i) {
    // use var because it's shorter
    var r=new Random();

    // build a quadrant
    // decide on a type...
    var q=""+"SWCR-".charAt(r.nextInt(5));
    // ...and append the color. If the type is "-" then append a "-" instead
    q+=q.equals("-")?'-':"ugbrycpw".charAt(r.nextInt(8));
    
    // decide what to return
    return 
    // shape case: build full shape
    i<1?
      // a shape consists of four layers
      // each layer starts with a :, cut the first one off
      (f(2)+f(2)+f(2)+f(3)).substring(1)

    // not the starting case, check for layer case
    :i<9?
      // build one layer. It either doesn't exist or contains four shapes
      // note: 3 overrides the random decision and always returns a layer
      i>2|r.nextInt(2)<1?
        // replace an empty layer with a newly generated one...
        (":"+f(9)+f(9)+f(9)+f(9)).replace(":--------",f(1)) 
        // ...or return a nonexistant layer
        :""
    // not the shape case nor the layer case, return the quadrant calculated above
    :q;
}
```

Comment: Here is an example of a lambda function with recursion [TIO](https://tio.run/##bY0xb8IwFIT3/IpTppgSC9amhA2JgSkj6uCGJHrBcSz7GQlF@e3BotCptzyd7nt3vbqpvL9cFxrs6Bh99DIwadkGUzONRq6KxIYfTTVqrbzHSZHBlOCpV@JZcTyH18/X0XDTNW5dsSPTlWiLf/nbSBcMsS/7Bc/fUK7z4q8@qsUOC@Xl5BoOzoDwgYxQYoM90lUabSuVtfqeUb4V@ESaimJe3ovV3XMzyDGwtHGDtcne/HYjxBObkzlZHg)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 64 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

A full program that prints the shape.

```
⊃{∊⍺':'⍵}/{∊((⊂'--'),,'RWCS'∘.,'urgbypcw')[?4⍴33]}⍣{∨/'-'≠⍺}¨⍳?4
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9TVXP2oo@tR7y51K/VHvVtr9UFcDY1HXU3qurrqmjo66kHhzsHqjzpm6OmolxalJ1UWJJera0bbmzzq3WJsHFv7qHcxUMsKfXVd9UedC4AG1R5a8ah3s70JAA&f=AwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=tradfn&n=f)

`?4` random integer between 1 and 4
 `... ¨⍳` call the function on the left this many times and collect the results in a list:

`{ ... }⍣{∨/'-'≠⍺}` until any char in the result is not `-`:
`'RWCS'∘.,'urgbypcw'` Cartesian product of the two strings
`,` flatten into a list of 2-char strings
`(⊂'--'),` prepend the empty quadrant
`( ... )[?4⍴33]` get elements at 4 random indices between 1 and 33.
`∊` flatten into a string

`{∊⍺':'⍵}/` join with `:`
`⊃` get the first element from the nested output

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>125</s> <s>120</s> <s>119</s> <s>115</s> <s>112</s> 118 bytes

To avoid the possibility of an empty layer, we force the 4th quadrant to be non-empty *if* all previous quadrants are already empty (+6 bytes 'cause I realised I'd screwed that up).

Need to figure out a way to shorten the selection of the characters.

```javascript
(r=x=>Math.random(g=s=>s[7]?l--?s+`:`+g``:s:g(s+`RWSC-`[c=r(5^s==`------`)]+`urgbypcw-`[c-4?r(8):8]))*x|0,l=r(4))=>g``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxDoIwFEV/p89aUhOMpPhgcHbRwYFgWlGqplLSItbEf6/o3U5Ozr2rUfnG3fqBjVlsMRKHAYutGq6JU93ZPohGj4WvVnVpGCs9lUJSLaXwQpOJdof9hsmqQUeWR48o2X8SaiqfTp/effP6eZaWjmQgshpgFj58bqYiBcBiOoutdSQgzwOl6wXnOTS289ZcEmM1aQlA/AI)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 117 bytes

*-2 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

Although this is not required, this solution has a uniform distribution.

```javascript
f=(k=(R=Math.random)()*4|0,q=R(n=4)*1185920)=>n--?f(k,q/33)+'SWCR-'[((q%=33)&35)%7]+'ugbrycpw-'[q>>2]:k?f(k-1)+':':''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYu7DoJAFAV/ZRvkXmCRZ1R0sbC2wcLCUCAvEdyFBTUm/juiMaeZnMlck0fSp7JqB8pFlo9jwaBmELF9MlxMmfBM3BBQ896W0bEIOPNQs@2lv3IsZCGndFtAbXRz10VdPRx3EVVPAJ3CpmPm@qgsYl29l2f5Stvn5LowdOKg/lbUnpJgmjoWQkI15JIwYq3JjzbE@aOuI0kF70WTm40ooQDE8QM)

Comment: Your comment made me go back to double check my solution and I realised I'd screwed up in how I was avoiding empty layers, preventing all possible outputs.

Comment: [117](https://tio.run/##LYu7DoJAFAV/ZRvkXmCRZ1R0sbC2wcLCUCAvEdyFBTUm/juiMaeZnMlck0fSp7JqB8pFlo9jwaBmELF9MlxMmfBM3BBQ896W0bEIOPNQs@2lv3IsZCGndFtAbXRz10VdPRx3EVVPAJ3CpmPm@qgsYl29l2f5Stvn5LowdOKg/lbUnpJgmjoWQkI15JIwYq3JjzbE@aOuI0kF70WTm40ooQDE8QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.5.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.5.1), 514 bytes

```
func a:
lda 0
sta $1
lda ""
sta $2
push 1
push 5
extern Random.Next(i32,i32)
pop $a
.lbl a
push $a
brfalse b
dec $a
push 0
pop $1
push ""
pop $3
.lbl c
push $1
push 4
sub
brfalse d
inc $1
push "RWSC-"
push 5
extern Random.Next(i32)
dup
push 1
add
substr
dup
push "-"
sub
len
brtrue f
dup
add
br e
.lbl f
push "urgbypcw"
push 8
extern Random.Next(i32)
dup
push 1
add
substr
add
.lbl e
push $3
swap
add
dup
pop $3
push "--------"
sub
len
brtrue c
push 0
pop $1
push ""
pop $3
br c
.lbl d
push $2
push $3
add
pop $2
push $a
brfalse a
push $2
push ":"
add
pop $2
br a
.lbl b
push $2
print
ret
end
```

Whew, this was one mammoth of a program to write.

This submission defines a function `a` which generates then prints the random shape string as is specified by the challenge.

---

**Explained:**

```
func a:
    ; $a = random value in [1, 4]
    ; $1 = loop counter for quadrants
    ; $2 = final string
    ; $3 = build string
    lda 0
    sta $1

    ; Initialize $2 to an empty string
    lda ""
    sta $2
    
    ; Initialize $a to the random value specified above
    push 1
    push 5
    extern Random.Next(i32,i32)
    pop $a

    .lbl a
        ; Stop looping if $a == 0
        push $a
        brfalse b
        dec $a

        ; Reset $1 and $3
        push 0
        pop $1
        push ""
        pop $3

        .lbl c
            ; Stop looping if $1 == 4
            push $1
            push 4
            sub
            brfalse d
            inc $1
            
            ; Get a random letter in "RWSC-"
            push "RWSC-"
            push 5
            extern Random.Next(i32)
            dup
            push 1
            add
            substr

            ; Check if the letter was "-"
            dup
            push "-"
            sub
            len
            brtrue f
            ; Letter was "-"; just add the other one
            dup
            add
            br e
        .lbl f
            ; Letter was not "-"; Get the color
            push "urgbypcw"
            push 8
            extern Random.Next(i32)
            dup
            push 1
            add
            substr

            ; Add the two parts together
            add
        .lbl e
            ; Add the new piece to $3
            push $3
            swap
            add
            dup
            pop $3

            ; Check $3.  If it's "--------", generate another layer
            push "--------"
            sub
            len
            brtrue c
            
            ; Reset the quadrants counter and build string
            push 0
            pop $1
            push ""
            pop $3

            br c
        .lbl d
            ; Append the layer to the result
            push $2
            push $3
            add
            pop $2
            
            ; If $a == 0, don't add the ":"
            push $a
            brfalse a
            push $2
            push ":"
            add
            pop $2
            br a
.lbl b
    ; Print the result
    push $2
    print
    ret
end
```

---

The first run of this code produce the following shape:
`--Cp----:--RgSg--:CgRwWbRr:WyWpWwWw`
[image: Shape]

More examples of shapes generated by the code:

```
--ScWyRp
WuWuCbRg:--RbSwRc:CwRuWrCb
CgSgRpCb:Cu--SrRb
Wc--CcCg:----CrRu
SyCbWc--
SrCbSc--:----WrWb
Ry--CgSr:--Cp--Sw
--CwWpCc:CbCpRcSy:CpWw--Cy:--Ru----
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 49 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
{╘4{4{"CRSW"w"bcgpruwy"w+v¶╛æ;û--}Γy}Γ'-8*a-}↔':u
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/60dQZJtUm1UrOQcHhSuVKScnpBUWl5ZVK5dplh7Y9mjr78DLrw7t1dWvPTa4EYnVdC61E3dpHbVPUrUr//wcA)

The first output was: `CwRuRrRw:RpSwSbRp:RcWpRpCu:CpWwWgWc`:
[image]

**Explanation:**

```python
{ ... }↔          # Do while false without popping:
 ╘                #  Empty the stack (in case we've encountered a fully empty result)
  4{              #  Loop 4 times:
    4{            #   Inner loop 4 times:
      "CRSW"w     #    Push a random character from "CRSW"
      "bcgpruwy"w #    Push a random character from "bcgpruwy"
       +          #    Concat these two characters together
        v         #    Push a random integer in the range [-2147483648,2147483647]
         ¶╛       #    If this integer is a prime number,
           æ      #    use the following four character as inner code-block:
            ;     #     Discard the earlier character pair
             û--  #     Push "--"
     }            #   After the inner loop:
      Γ           #   Wrap the top four items into a list
       y          #   And join this list together to a single string
   }              #  After the outer loop:
    Γ             #  Wrap the top (up to) four items into a list
     '-8*a-      '#  Remove any strings consisting of 8 "-"
}↔                # After the do-while false:
  ':u            '# Join the list with ":" delimiter
                  # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Compressed strings are pretty mediocre in MathGolf, so unfortunately it won't save any bytes here. `"CRSW"w` can be [`` ╖╖`'w+wδ ``](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1GlAlKBerl1@bsv//wA) which is 1 byte longer, and `"bcgpruwy"` can be [`╕█≈║☺ 'ußy`](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9tYXRoZ29sZv//4pWV4paI4omI4pWR4pi6ICd1w595//8) which is the same byte-count.

Answer (score 1):

## [FMSLogo](https://fmslogo.sourceforge.io/manual), 106 bytes

```
show bl map[word pick bf invoke[(crossmap "word ? ? ? ?)]se[--]crossmap "word[RWCS urgbycpw]":]random 1500
```

Don't try it online. The [calormen.com](https://www.calormen.com/jslogo/#) logo interpreter does not support "templates" (which is what logo calls anonymous functions) on map, only procedure names; it's error messages also leave something to be desired.
The program works in FMSLogo 8.3.2 and propably MSWLogo and UCBLogo as well, as FMSLogo is based on them.

Explaination:

- Logo is based on lisp but allows omitting parentheses around procedures that use their default arity.
- `crossmap` generates all possible combinations of the members of its inputs, which can be given in a list. The first input is a function, or "template", which is passed each combination to combine them.
- I don't know a better way to remove the empty layer yet, so the first `crossmap` generates a 1185921 element list of every possible layer and then `bf` removes the first one. That's why this program takes approximately 27 seconds to run on my laptop.
- Numbers can be coerced to strings in logo, so `map` maps the big instruction list in the middle over the characters of a random number, which has some length between one and four. `repeat 1+random 4[...]` would not output the concatenation of the results, and using `map[...]iseq random 4 4` is 4 characters longer.
- I would not be able to tell, of course, but maybe some correlation in the random number generator makes some shapes actually impossible. I am not going to investigate.

Anonymous functions can not be called the normal way, unlike in javascript for example. They must be called by `apply`, `map`, or similar, which is why I consider

```
[bl map[word pick bf invoke[(crossmap "word ? ? ? ?)]se[--]crossmap "word[RWCS urgbycpw]":]random 1500]
```

to be an invalid submission.

Alternative much faster 5 characters longer solution, which, unlike the submission, can propably produce empty output:

### FMSLogo, 111 bytes

```
show bl map[invoke[if ?="--------: ["][?]]word map[pick se[--]crossmap "word[RWCS urgbcypw]]1234 ":]random 1500
```

Sample shape: `CpCuRpSc:SwSuCcWr:Sb--RwSb` (everyone seems to do this)

[image: A Shape]

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 158 bytes

```bash
p='eval printf %s, '
s=$($p {S,W,C,R}{u,g,b,r,y,c,p,w})--
l=`$p{$s}{$s}{$s}{$s}`
$p{$l}:{$l}:{$l}:{$l}|tr , \\n|sed -E "s/-{4}(:|$)//g;/(^|:)(:|$)/d"|shuf -n1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GCpaUlaboWN-cV2KqnliXmKBQUZeaVpCmoFusoqHMV26poqBQoVAfrhOs46wTVVpfqpOsk6RTpVOok6xTolNdq6upy5dgmqBRUqxTXIuMELpBYTq0VKlFTUqSgoxATk1dTnJqioOuqoFSsr1ttUqthVaOiqa-fbq2vEVdjpQnhpijVFGeUpino5hlCXAl1LMzRAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 155 bytes

```
r=RandomInteger
c=RandomChoice
t=Table
StringRiffle[StringJoin/@(Nest[#/.c@#->"--"&,#,r@2]&/@t[t[#<>#2&@@c@*Characters/@{"RWSC","urgbypcw"},4],r@3+1]),":"]
```

The distribution of the non-empty quadrants is uniform, but the distribution of shapes is not, as empty quadrants are generated after the fact.

*TIO* requires two extra bytes for symbol assignment so that the output can be printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1PC4IwHEDvfowJ0p/ZyDpFyg881SFCgw6yw1xThzpj/iIi@uxLqOPj8Xi9wEb1ArUUztk4E@Y29AeDqlbWk39Om0FL5WF8EWWnvDbO0WpTZ7qqOlX84Dhow2B2UiMWPltJ8MOEhCEJqE8tRDxggMWk9okfBQASFmkjrJCo7MjgTbJrnhJKHrYuX3f5JB@65VO4Wa75nJId4e48bRBa9wU)

Comment: [122 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpNCoMwEEDhfY8x6wgKrrQpAXsAUaGLkMU4TTTgHzFSSmmuntrt@96MftQzeksYTcFjh/2kJfLu2Ca9i2pEh@S128UHmkdbAYPDDf17oxd8A4W8RClJOkbCJZlSikOSQInXGwA7O29wGbTIlQqtd3YZGmvMpAMUcKE/Pte5GldLOt5XWZ@HF4ZlaariDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>117 116</s> 114 bytes

```javascript
f=(k=n=5*~R(4))=>++n?n%5?R(~k%5)?'--'+f(k+1):'SWCR'[R(4)]+'ugbrycpw'[R(8)]+f(k):':'+f(n):''
R=n=>Math.random()*n|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBC4IwHAXwe99D9v87lAkJok0PnbusQ4fosMxZaZtMM4Pwq9uEd3g8frynHGVf2kc3BGOyKO4CDdc89mcBW0SeU6oL7cWFgLnxYixIEBCqoKERpuR42gtyXuWFknd9td@y@6xD4gaHHElXrV0hG@GO84Mc7qGV@mZegL7@sUUZCxNn2UTpLmIsw9Lo3rRV2JoaFCAufw)

If already \$k\$ empty in this layer, then there's \$\frac 1{4-k}\$ probably be not empty, aka 1 when already 3 empty