# Draw me a shape

Tags: code-golf, geometry, graphical-output

The game [shapez.io](https://shapez.io) has a *lot* of shapes. In [my previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233709/make-me-a-shape/233738#233738), the object was to generate a random code for a shape. Now, your challenge is to render a shape.

## Specs

### Shapes

Each shape has a unique shortcode, for example:

[image]

is `CrWgRuSp` - clockwise from top right, **r**ed **c**ircle, **g**reen **w**edge, **u**ncolored **r**ectangle, **p**urple **s**tar.

A *quadrant* is one of Rectangle (`R`), Circle (`C`), Star (`S`) or Wedge (`W`) painted with one of the below colours. The shortcode for these quadrants is the code for the shape concatenated to the code for the color, so a yellow star would be `Sy`. A quadrant can also be empty, with the code `--`.

Four quadrants concatenated together make a layer, the quadrants going clockwise from top-right. Layers will never be empty (`--------`).

Finally, between one and four layers stacked on top of each other (joined by `:`, lowest first) make a shape. For example, `CyCyCyCy:SrSrSrSr` looks like:

[image]

### Colours

The colours are as follows:

- uncolored / `u` / grey - #AAAAAA
- red / `r` - #FC666A
- blue / `b` - #66A7FF
- green / `g` - #78FF65
- purple / `p` - #DD66FF
- yellow / `y` - #FDF52A
- cyan / `c` - #87FFF5
- white / `w` - #FFFFFF
- border - #555555

### Sizes

Given a constant \$a\$, the width of a single border, the shape sizes are as follows:

| Shape | Spec | Image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Circle | A perfectly circular arc going out to 9a each way | [image] |
| Rectangle | A square with side 9a | [image] |
| Wedge | A shape with one side going out to 9a, the other going along the base to 5.75a before going diagonally to 9a. | [image] |
| Star | Both edges going out to 5.75a before going diagonally out to 9a and meeting up. | [image] |

These need to be multiplied by the scale factor for the correct layer:

- layer 1 (bottom) - 1
- layer 2 - \$\frac{7}{9}\$
- layer 3 - \$\frac{19}{36}\$
- layer 4 - \$\frac{5}{18}\$

You should render your shape with a value of \$a ≥ 10\$ pixels - your choice of the size.

Note: All sizes are approximations - If you have a better estimate, let me know.

All sizes are flexible within 1%.

You may take either a shape shortcode (layers joined by `:`), a list of layer shortcodes, or a list of lists of quadrant shortcodes.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

## Testcases

`CyCyCyCy:SrSrSrSr` - [image]

`CuCuCuCu:------Cy` - [image]

`------Cg:------Cr` - [image]

`CrSyWgRb` - [image]

`Cr------:------Cr:Cr------:------Cr` - [image]

Note that you *don't* have to render the pale-grey circle in the background.

Comment: Will a ascii art approximation be valid?

Comment: @JohanduToit No, has to be graphical. You can output as, say, PBM or SVG though.

Comment: In java, when using lambdas, can you prep the window in advance and in the function only do the graphical stuff or do you need to also create the window in the function itself?

Comment: @Jadefalke I don't think so, as it needs to be a full function/ program which draws a shape when run.

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES10) + SVG (HTML5), <s>407</s> <s>387</s> <s>365</s> 340 bytes

```js
g=s=>s.split`:`.map(s=>s.match(/../g)||[]);f=
l=>'<svg viewBox=-1350,-1350,2700,2700 stroke=#555>'+l.map((q,i)=>q.map(([s,c],o)=>`<path d=M0,0v-${{C:'36a36,36,0,0,1,36,',R:'36h36v',W:'23l36,-13v',S:'23l36,-13l-13,'}[s]}36z fill=#${"FDF52A/FC666A/66A7FF/87FFF5/AAA//FFF/78FF65/D6F".split`/`[parseInt(c,36)%17%9]} transform=rotate(${o*90})scale(${q=35-i*9+!i}) stroke-width=${108/q} />`))
```

```html
<input oninput=o.innerHTML=f(g(this.value))><div id=o>
```

Takes input as a list of list and outputs SVG source parseable by HTML5. Note that as it's scalable I can't really specify what the value of `a` is, it's always just big enough to fit the width of the window. At the start is the `svg` element definition, followed by a `path` element for each of the (possibly 16) quadrants, sized, coloured and rotated appropriately. Edit: Saved 22 bytes thanks to @Arnauld (although 7 of those bytes should have been obvious, sigh...). Saved a further 18 bytes directly and 7 bytes indirectly thanks to @JohanduToit.

Comment: Nice! You can take a list of layers, so you don't need to split by `:`.

Comment: @emanresuA Sure, once I can work out how to amend the snippet to pass a list of lists...

Comment: `<input oninput='o.innerHTML=f(this.value.split\`:\`)'><div id=o>`, or just create a wrapper for f that splits by `:` before calling.

Comment: @emanresuA As I mentioned, I might as well pass a list of lists if I can...

Comment: Do that then.  `f(this.value.split\`:\`.map(x=>x.match(/../g)))`.

Comment: (I had to tweak that slightly so that it wouldn't error out as you type.)

Comment: I think you can save 13 bytes by using [this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/a@v9T8tMyfHVlmlWsnNxc3UyFHfzdnMzMxRH4jN3dz0LYCEm6m@o6Ojvj6QpW9u4eZmZqrvYuampFdckJNZkqCfEF2QWFSc6plXolEcbRirY2ymqWpormoZW/tfS/8/AA) for the colors.

Comment: @Arnauld D'oh, I went to all the trouble of factoring out the `v-` for each shape and overlooked the 7 byte saving of factoring out the `#` for each colour...

Comment: Could you also factorize a trailing `36` for the shapes? Another minor golf: using `q.map(([S,C],o)=>` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: `n*=35-i*9+!i` saves another byte.

Comment: [360 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZBBb6MwEIX/CttS2U4NJrFwmrRGoqmQ9tBLethDFMleAoTWwQRbtCrlt2edZg97WWnm6b3vMDOaV9lLk3d1a4NG74pTxQ1PTGhaVVuxFOFBtvCbHKTN95CEIanQ19dmi@5Lj58UT8CD6Suvr4v3R/3BgymNI3zR2Ty6iGdsp98Kfh3HcQJuVVgqaZ/dZHjENeLJ8XsN3Bicb7F2QDy00u69HX@OcNQH/iD8AQ6rJaBMUoZdOY6nZwPw@oz3lPUA/1qCGVWOugNcfPknKtcYjBuzRSNlYvz0ylopfu0PV9lTFs9Skq0YYylxPc8ycucki0mapoQ4R@Z3WcZi8sSyq7/fIWLTys4UPxsLc3cKupnObxbb0bOdbEypuwMHnbbSFtAf9GQRjcjkUp3TkdM4qCeL2x/1iMDlO8F7vbN77g90Qhk5jh5JBELhq64bIU65boxWRah0BUtYQbDqXrp1tf69/L8BCKH70x8). I think you can save a few more with `transform="matrix..."`

Comment: @JohanduToit I'd tried `scale` before but couldn't work out how to adjust the stroke width, thanks for the tip! This also saves me the nested template (-5 bytes) and I also golfed two more bytes (`3*36=108` and you used quotes when you just need a space).

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZBPT@MwEMW/SoAi2@DEaaO4f8CRskWW9sClHDhUlWLSJDXrxmlsBbQhn73r0h72gjTz9N7vMDOad9EJk7eysX6tt8WxYoYlJjCNkjZbZMFeNPCb7IXNd5AEAanQ19d6gx5Kjx0VS8Cj6Sqvk8XHL/3J/HEUh/isk2l4Fs/YVv8p2E0cxwm4V0GphH12k@EBS8SSw/cauDY432DtQPbYCLvztuw5xGHnj/p@uQARFRHFrhzD45MBeHXCu4h2AL8uwCRSjrrlLr78F5VrDIa12QwR/euVUil2M@qv@ROPJynhS0ppSlxPOSczJzwmaZoS4hyZzjinMXmi/PryFpKtG9Ga4ndtYe7uQLfj6e18M3i2FbUpdbtnrbbCFnDU67t5OCCTC3VKBxbFvryb31/JAV2@4n/Ird2xUT8OZ@QweCTJEAretayz7Jjr2mhVBEpXsIQVBMv2pV1Vq7fFzwYghB6O/wA) Loosing the unnecessary parentheses =)

Comment: @JohanduToit ... why didn't you say that last time? (I had put them in by force of habit because you need them for expression statements, but there's no such ambiguity in template strings.)

Comment: SVG will ignore text between shapes, see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0cz1vws/). This means that you can use `map` instead of `flatMap` and drop the `join` at the end. [340 bytes](https://bit.ly/3En3uVO)

Answer (score 4):

## LaTeX+Tikz, 770 bytes

This solution uses tikz's `scope` to implement the rotating and scaling.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}\usetikzlibrary{math}\begin{document}\def\h#1{\definecolor#1{HTML}}\h u{AAAAAA}\h r{FC666A}\h h{66A7FF}\h g{78FF65}\h p{DD66FF}\h y{FDF52A}\h c{87FFF5}\h w{FFFFFF}\def\R#1{\draw[fill=#1]rectangle(,);}\def\C#1{\draw[fill=#1](0,0)--(0,1)arc(90:0:1cm)--cycle;}\def\W#1{\draw[fill=#1](0,0)-|(,)--(0,0.639)--cycle;}\def\S#1{\draw[fill=#1](0,0)--(0,0.639)--(1,1)--(0.639,0)--cycle;}\expandafter\def\csname-\endcsname#1{\path(0,0)--(,);}\def\c#1#2{\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}\def~#1{\tikz[draw=black!66,line width=.11cm]{\def\a{#1}\foreach\l[count=\i from 0]in\a{\begin{scope}[scale=(37-9*\i+!\i)/36]\foreach\q[count=\j from 0]in\l\begin{scope}[rotate around={-90*\j:(0,0)}]{\expandafter\c\q}\end{scope};\end{scope}}}}\enddocument
```

### Result

This is the resulting pdf converted to svg with inkscape:

```html
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) --><svg   version="1.1"   id="svg2"   xml:space="preserve"   width="922.13867"   height="83.568001"   viewBox="0 0 922.13867 83.568001"   sodipodi:docname="document.svg"   inkscape:version="1.1 (c4e8f9ed74, 2021-05-24)"   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs     id="defs6" /><sodipodi:namedview     id="namedview4"     pagecolor="#ffffff"     bordercolor="#666666"     borderopacity="1.0"     inkscape:pageshadow="2"     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"     showgrid="false"     inkscape:zoom="5.5349593"     inkscape:cx="702.53453"     inkscape:cy="45.980465"     inkscape:window-width="1920"     inkscape:window-height="1042"     inkscape:window-x="0"     inkscape:window-y="18"     inkscape:window-maximized="1"     inkscape:current-layer="g8" /><g     id="g8"     inkscape:groupmode="layer"     inkscape:label="document"     transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,83.568)"><g       id="g10"       transform="translate(83.002,29.921)"><g         id="g12"><g           id="g14"><g             id="g16"><g               id="g18"><g                 id="g20"><path                   d="M 0,0 V 29.92122 H 29.92122 V 0 Z"                   style="fill:#a8a8a8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                   id="path22" /></g></g><g               id="g24" /><g               id="g26" /><g               id="g28" /></g></g></g><g         id="g30"         transform="translate(71.212)"><g           id="g32"><g             id="g34"><g               id="g36"><g                 id="g38"><g                   id="g40"><path                     d="M 0,0 V 29.92122 C 16.52524,29.92122 29.92122,16.52524 29.92122,0 Z"                     style="fill:#a8a8a8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                     id="path42" /></g></g><g                 id="g44" /><g                 id="g46" /><g                 id="g48" /></g></g></g><g           id="g50"           transform="translate(71.211)"><g             id="g52"><g               id="g54"><g                 id="g56"><g                   id="g58"><g                     id="g60"><path                       d="M 0,0 H 29.92122 V 29.92122 L 0,19.11987 Z"                       style="fill:#a8a8a8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                       id="path62" /></g></g><g                   id="g64" /><g                   id="g66" /><g                   id="g68" /></g></g></g><g             id="g70"             transform="translate(71.212)"><g               id="g72"><g                 id="g74"><g                   id="g76"><g                     id="g78"><g                       id="g80"><path                         d="M 0,0 V 19.11987 L 29.92122,29.92122 19.11987,0 Z"                         style="fill:#a8a8a8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                         id="path82" /></g></g><g                     id="g84" /><g                     id="g86" /><g                     id="g88" /></g></g></g><g               id="g90"               transform="translate(72.629,1.417)"><g                 id="g92"><g                   id="g94"><g                     id="g96"><g                       id="g98"><g                         id="g100"><path                           d="M 0,0 V 29.92122 C 16.52524,29.92122 29.92122,16.52524 29.92122,0 Z"                           style="fill:#fdf52a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                           id="path102" /></g></g><g                       id="g104"><g                         id="g106"><path                           d="M 0,0 H 29.92122 C 29.92122,-16.52524 16.52524,-29.92122 0,-29.92122 Z"                           style="fill:#fdf52a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                           id="path108" /></g></g><g                       id="g110"><g                         id="g112"><path                           d="m 0,0 v -29.92122 c -16.52524,0 -29.92122,13.39598 -29.92122,29.92122 z"                           style="fill:#fdf52a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                           id="path114" /></g></g><g                       id="g116"><g                         id="g118"><path                           d="m 0,0 h -29.92122 c 0,16.52524 13.39598,29.92122 29.92122,29.92122 z"                           style="fill:#fdf52a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                           id="path120" /></g></g></g><g                     id="g122"><g                       id="g124"><g                         id="g126"><path                           d="M 0,0 V 14.08838 L 22.04732,22.04732 14.08838,0 Z"                           style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                           id="path128" /></g></g><g                       id="g130"><g                         id="g132"><path                           d="M 0,0 H 14.08838 L 22.04732,-22.04732 0,-14.08838 Z"                           style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                           id="path134" /></g></g><g                       id="g136"><g                         id="g138"><path                           d="M 0,0 V -14.08838 L -22.04732,-22.04732 -14.08838,0 Z"                           style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                           id="path140" /></g></g><g                       id="g142"><g                         id="g144"><path                           d="M 0,0 H -14.08838 L -22.04732,22.04732 0,14.08838 Z"                           style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                           id="path146" /></g></g></g></g></g><g                 id="g148"                 transform="translate(72.629)"><g                   id="g150"><g                     id="g152"><g                       id="g154"><g                         id="g156"><g                           id="g158"><path                             d="M 0,0 V 29.92122 C 16.52524,29.92122 29.92122,16.52524 29.92122,0 Z"                             style="fill:#a8a8a8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                             id="path160" /></g></g><g                         id="g162"><g                           id="g164"><path                             d="M 0,0 H 29.92122 C 29.92122,-16.52524 16.52524,-29.92122 0,-29.92122 Z"                             style="fill:#a8a8a8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                             id="path166" /></g></g><g                         id="g168"><g                           id="g170"><path                             d="m 0,0 v -29.92122 c -16.52524,0 -29.92122,13.39598 -29.92122,29.92122 z"                             style="fill:#a8a8a8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                             id="path172" /></g></g><g                         id="g174"><g                           id="g176"><path                             d="m 0,0 h -29.92122 c 0,16.52524 13.39598,29.92122 29.92122,29.92122 z"                             style="fill:#a8a8a8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                             id="path178" /></g></g></g><g                       id="g180"><g                         id="g182" /><g                         id="g184" /><g                         id="g186" /><g                         id="g188"><g                           id="g190"><path                             d="m 0,0 h -22.04732 c 0,12.17654 9.87078,22.04732 22.04732,22.04732 z"                             style="fill:#fdf52a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                             id="path192" /></g></g></g></g></g><g                   id="g194"                   transform="translate(72.63,-1.417)"><g                     id="g196"><g                       id="g198"><g                         id="g200"><g                           id="g202" /><g                           id="g204" /><g                           id="g206" /><g                           id="g208"><g                             id="g210"><path                               d="m 0,0 h -29.92122 c 0,16.52524 13.39598,29.92122 29.92122,29.92122 z"                               style="fill:#78ff65;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                               id="path212" /></g></g></g><g                         id="g214"><g                           id="g216" /><g                           id="g218" /><g                           id="g220" /><g                           id="g222"><g                             id="g224"><path                               d="m 0,0 h -22.04732 c 0,12.17654 9.87078,22.04732 22.04732,22.04732 z"                               style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                               id="path226" /></g></g></g></g></g><g                     id="g228"                     transform="translate(71.211,1.417)"><g                       id="g230"><g                         id="g232"><g                           id="g234"><g                             id="g236"><g                               id="g238"><path                                 d="M 0,0 V 29.92122 C 16.52524,29.92122 29.92122,16.52524 29.92122,0 Z"                                 style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                                 id="path240" /></g></g><g                             id="g242"><g                               id="g244"><path                                 d="M 0,0 H 19.11987 L 29.92122,-29.92122 0,-19.11987 Z"                                 style="fill:#fdf52a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                                 id="path246" /></g></g><g                             id="g248"><g                               id="g250"><path                                 d="M 0,0 H -29.92122 V -29.92122 L 0,-19.11987 Z"                                 style="fill:#78ff65;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                                 id="path252" /></g></g><g                             id="g254"><g                               id="g256"><path                                 d="M 0,0 H -29.92122 V 29.92122 H 0 Z"                                 style="fill:#66a7ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                                 id="path258" /></g></g></g></g></g><g                       id="g260"                       transform="translate(71.212,-1.417)"><g                         id="g262"><g                           id="g264"><g                             id="g266"><g                               id="g268"><g                                 id="g270"><path                                   d="M 0,0 V 29.92122 C 16.52524,29.92122 29.92122,16.52524 29.92122,0 Z"                                   style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                                   id="path272" /></g></g><g                               id="g274" /><g                               id="g276" /><g                               id="g278" /></g><g                             id="g280"><g                               id="g282" /><g                               id="g284" /><g                               id="g286" /><g                               id="g288"><g                                 id="g290"><path                                   d="m 0,0 h -22.04732 c 0,12.17654 9.87078,22.04732 22.04732,22.04732 z"                                   style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                                   id="path292" /></g></g></g><g                             id="g294"><g                               id="g296"><g                                 id="g298"><path                                   d="M 0,0 V 14.9606 C 8.26262,14.9606 14.9606,8.26262 14.9606,0 Z"                                   style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                                   id="path300" /></g></g><g                               id="g302" /><g                               id="g304" /><g                               id="g306" /></g><g                             id="g308"><g                               id="g310" /><g                               id="g312" /><g                               id="g314" /><g                               id="g316"><g                                 id="g318"><path                                   d="m 0,0 h -7.8739 c 0,4.34868 3.52522,7.8739 7.8739,7.8739 z"                                   style="fill:#fc666a;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#575757;stroke-width:2.83484;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"                                   id="path320" /></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></g></svg>
```

### Formatted Code and Usage

````tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
% define the color shorthands
\def\h#1{\definecolor#1{HTML}}
\h u{AAAAAA}
\h r{FC666A}
\h b{66A7FF}
\h g{78FF65}
\h p{DD66FF}
\h y{FDF52A}
\h c{87FFF5}
\h w{FFFFFF}
% define commands that draw a shape
\def\R#1{\draw[fill=#1]rectangle(,);}
\def\C#1{\draw[fill=#1](0,0)--(0,1)arc(90:0:1cm)--cycle;}
\def\W#1{\draw[fill=#1](0,0)-|(,)--(0,0.639)--cycle;}
\def\S#1{\draw[fill=#1](0,0)--(0,0.639)--(1,1)--(0.639,0)--cycle;}
\expandafter\def\csname-\endcsname#1{\path(0,0)--(,);}
% define the command that parses the shape and the colour and calls the shape command
\def\c#1#2{\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def~#1{
    \tikz[draw=black!66,line width=.11cm]{
        \def\a{#1}
        \foreach \l [count=\i from 0] in \a{
            \begin{scope}[scale=(37-9*\i+!\i)/36]
                \foreach \q [count=\j from 0] in \l
                    \begin{scope}[rotate around={-90*\j:(0,0)}]{
                        \expandafter\c\q
                    }
                    \end{scope}
                ;
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
}
~{{Ru,--,--,--}}
~{{Cu,--,--,--}}
~{{Wu,--,--,--}}
~{{Su,--,--,--}}

~{{Cy,Cy,Cy,Cy},{Sr,Sr,Sr,Sr}}
~{{Cu,Cu,Cu,Cu},{--,--,--,Cy}}
~{{--,--,--,Cg},{--,--,--,Cr}}

~{{Cr,Sy,Wg,Rb}}
~{{Cr,--,--,--},{--,--,--,Cr},{Cr,--,--,--},{--,--,--,Cr}}
\enddocument
```
````

Comment: Very nice work! There's some room for improvement here. I'll give it a shot in a couple minutes. Hope you'll like my suggestions... Standard considerations: Use `scoped` instead of `\begin{scope}` and `\end{scope}`, try `\definecolorset`, etc. Will not post it as "own solution" unless I'll find a completely new approach.

Comment: Hey, I brought it down to 625: overleaf.com/read/pmbmkqgrdpqj Here's what I did: Introduced two abbreviations, improved accuracy (23/36 instead of 0.639 and introducing 555555 as color s (for stroke)) a little bit, went with the standard considerations mentioned above, threw out a couple of superfluous packages and libraries, watched out for white space and tried to avoid it as much as possible... So, it's still basically your work -- with some minor tweaks saving about 18% of the bytes. Hope you appreciate it.

Comment: ... 623 now, maybe going down a little more ... anyways ... I stop commenting for anti-spam reasons ;-)